# Alter script not working on server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an alter script to change datatype from `nvarchar` to `float` which works fine in my local machine but fails to work on 2012 server.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my script or any changes need to be done on server?

My alter script is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
  ALTER COLUMN mycolumn FLOAT
```

and I get this error:

> Msg 8114, level 16,state 5, line 6
>   Error converting datatype nvarchar to float

Comment: Which database do you use (MySQL, SQL-Server, ...)? What is the error message?

Comment: you may get an error if a value in some row can't be converted to the new type.

Comment: Hi Jens, I am using SQL-Server. It shows Msg 8114, level 16,state 5, line 6, error converting  datatype nvarchar to float.

Comment: use parsefloat(data)

Comment: Kishan, can you please tell me how using parsefloat(data) as per my above requirement.

Comment: `SELECT * from mytable WHERE mycolumn is not null and TRY_CONVERT(float,mycolumn) is null` should find you the row(s) of data that are causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If it is throwing an error 'Error converting data type varchar to float.' then it is obvious that there are some values in the varchar field which cannot be converted to float. If you can tell us more about the error being thrown, it will be easier to understand the issue.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, it throws error message as follows :
Msg 8114, level 16,state 5, line 6, error converting datatype nvarchar to float.

Comment: remove all the data causing this error by using query suggested by Damien and run your alter statement.